# targeting multiple classes at once

Tags: html, css, hover

I have a css based hover/click effect on my page that works great. When the item (.print) is hovered a full color image (.print_photo) appears to the right. When the item is clicked the image fades to gray and a text box (.print_text) appears.

The clicking function only works when you hold the click down, I would like it to stay visible once clicked until another item is clicked. Is this possible?

(I don't have enough reputation to post the image once I do I will post it) image size is width:620px; height:490px;

**CSS**

```css
#bgtextbox{
    width:320px;
    height:391px;
    background-color:#BCBEC0;
    margin:130px 0 0 0px;
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    z-index:1;
    }

/* hover/click START */
.print{
        width:340px;
        height:40px;
        background-color:#E6E7E8;
        margin:6px 0 0 0px;
        position:relative;
        text-align:center;
        font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
        font-weight:bold;
        line-height:40px;
        border:1px solid #E6E7E8;
        z-index:12;
        }

.print_photo{
        width:620px;
        height:490px;
        margin:-48px 0 0 370px;
        text-align:center;
        background-repeat:no-repeat;
        position:absolute;  
        z-index:2;      
        }

.print_photo img{
            opacity:0;
            max-height:100%;
            max-width:100%;
            } 

.print_text{
            width:430px;
            height:150px;
            margin:292px 0 0 397px;
            position:absolute;
            border-radius: 20px / 20px;
            opacity:.75;
            color:transparent;
            z-index:13;
            }


.print:hover{
            border:1px solid #F15A24;
            cursor:pointer;             
            }

.print:hover ~ .print_photo img{
                            opacity:1;
                            -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;                                       
                            }

.print:active ~ .print_photo img{   
                        filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
                        opacity:.5;
                        -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                      transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
                        }

.print:active ~ .print_text{                            
                    background-color:#000;
                    color:#FFF;
                    }
    /* END */
```

**HTML**

```html
<div id="bgtextbox">
  <div class="print">PRINT</div>
  <div class="print_photo"><img src="images/print.png"</div></div>
  <div class="print_text">PRINT TEXT GOES HERE</div>
</div>
```

Comment: You have to have some kind of javascript to set the style once clicked, CSS doesnt set styles on click.

Comment: I don't completely understand JS, and all of the templates or examples I find are only for one element. @PatrickEvans

Comment: You can add event handlers to multiple elements, but *event delegation* is probably what you should be using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will be needing Javascript for this. There is actually a technique to do this with radio buttons and pure css, but as it is actually a hack, and quiet dirty, I will move straight to the jquery solution.

You would have to add some selectors to your existing css:

```
.print.active  ~ .print_text, .print:active ~ .print_text {
.print.active ~ .print_photo img, .print:active ~ .print_photo img {
```

As you will notice, the styling will now not only be triggered when the mouse is down(:active), but also when it contains a class `.active`

With a few line of jQuery you can toggle that class on click:

```
// when print is clicked
$('.print').click(function() {
    // remove the old active
    $('.print.active').removeClass('active');
    // add the active class to the trigger
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

A working example can be found here:
http://jsfiddle.net/WRwVf/

**edit:**
To include this code in your page, you would have to load the jQuery library first. Add something like this as the last node of your body:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Below this you could then put your script. Note that it would be wise to put it inside an 'ready' event as well. Something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// when the DOM is ready
$(document).ready(function() {
   /* - The above code goes here - */
});
</script>
```

You can also put the script in a separate .js file, and load it in the same way as the jquery library, but as it is just a few lines of code, this will be considered overkill by some, as the extra http request would slow your page down.

Comment: jQuery was never mentioned. you do not need to bring in an entire library to do this, even if you use a JS solution.

Comment: An extra 32kb file just so you can write 3 lines of code?  You call that "working"?

Comment: 90% of the time the library will already be in the browsers cache if you use something like google CDN, so that is not really an issue imo. But this is not worth the discussion...

Comment: the answer is not to defend jQuery usage for a menial task. its to learn javascript.

Comment: Where would I place the jQuery? @PeterVR

Comment: @deechtheleech I've added some instructions to my answer

Comment: I'm a bit lost... I've added the css, called out the script, then the last block quote^ goes under the call out? And the jQuery goes inside that last block quote?

Comment: have a look at the html section of my updated fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/WRwVf/5/

Comment: I was messing with the fiddle for a bit and I got it working. But now I have to apply that same function to seven more items. With your fiddle you created a second bgtextbox that opens/closes in a new position. My single bgtextbox is holding eight items similar to .print and my images are stacked in the live area. Would I have to change up the jQuery?

Comment: probably you would have to make some small changes yes. If you post your html in the fiddle, I will see what I can do...

Comment: Thank you Peter! Am I able to upload images on there?

Comment: the actual images are not relevant, just use placeholders like i did

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/JjQC6/5/ I took the liberty to optimize your css / html a bit (classes are meant to use multiple times, so you should do just that). Got rid of the sibling selector as well, so the code should work in legacy browsers (except for the transition / effects). jQuery is virtually unchanged.

Comment: Looks beautiful man! I appreciate all of your help! I had one class for all of them when I first got it working, the reason I had multiple classes for each item was for the positioning. But THANK YOU!!! This thing has been giving me a headache for like a week.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to need to use JS for this. Have some JS that gets run onClick of one of your .print elements which adds a 'selected' class to it, removing that class from all other elements first.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution is to use JS for this, as @DuncanLock recommends. The more creative (but CSS-based) way to do it is to create a sibling of `.print` that is a checkbox.

```html
<div id="bgtextbox">
    <div class="print">PRINT</div>
    <input type="checkbox" class="print_checkbox" />
    <div class="print_photo"><img src="images/print.png"</div></div>
    <div class="print_text">PRINT TEXT GOES HERE</div>
</div>
```

Set its CSS to be:

```css
.print_checkbox {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    right:0;
    bottom:0;
    opacity:0.01;
}
```

So it fills up the whole area the div does, and looks transparent. I should point out to casual observers that you would need to set the `position` of the parent (`#bgtextbox`) as well, but he already did that in his CSS.

Then have the CSS use the `:checked` psuedo-class to show the img based on checked (clicked) or not. Just change this:

```
.print:active ~ .print_photo img
```

To this:

```
.print_checked:checked + .print_photo img
```

You'll still need the JS solution for IE8-, but you would have already needed it anyway using the `~` CSS selector, so there isn't any difference in terms of browser compatibility.

Just food for thought. This isn't exactly WYSIWYG coding methodology, but if you're the kind of developer that tries to leverage CSS over JS whenever possible (like me), it's a cool little trick.

Comment: As he states he only wants the picture to remain visible, until another 'button' is clicked, you would need to do this with a radio button: http://jsfiddle.net/WRwVf/ But I still think it is a hack, and I would not use it in real life. It is just semantically incorrect to add elements just for styling... I agree You should always try to go for a js free solution, but in this case I would go for js (jQuery even ;-) )

Comment: i made it clear what this was ... and im glad that you agree with yourself about using jQuery haha

Answer (score 0):

You have to use JS to set a class, then remove it when needed.

HTML

```html
<div id="bgtextbox">
     <div id="print" class="print">PRINT</div>
     <div class="print_photo"><img src="images/print.png"</div></div>
     <div class="print_text">PRINT TEXT GOES HERE</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
.printactive ~ .print_photo img{   
    filter: grayscale(100%);
    -webkit-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -moz-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -ms-filter: grayscale(100%);
    -o-filter: grayscale(100%);
    opacity:.5;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: opacity 1s ease-in-out;
}

.printactive ~ .print_text{                            
    background-color:#000;
    color:#FFF;
}
```

JS

```js
document.getElementById("print").addEventListener("click",activatePrintDiv);

function activatePrintDiv(){
    var pclass = this.getAttribute("class");
    this.setAttribute("class",pclass+" printactive");
}
```

Comment: This functions, but it is only part of the solution:  http://cssdeck.com/labs/65kdnk1c.  There's no code here to disable the click when other elements are clicked on.

Comment: Well i would hope he would be able to fill in that part himself.